# Роутер на Debian

Tags: маршрутизация, linux

Есть сферический сервер с 4 интерфейсами: eth0 - локалка; eth(1,2,3) - uplink'и - статика. Хочется поднять на этом хозяйстве роутер, чтобы с локалки можно было ходить в любой uplink. При этом в eth1 торчит интернет, т.е. это должен быть default gateway. А вот на два других уже нужно забивать статические маршруты по выбранным подсетям.С любого из интерфейсов пакет должен уходить в сеть с адресом этого интерфейса, т.е. через NAT.

Просьба подсказать чем пользоваться, чтобы собрать такую схему. iptables - это понятно. iproute нужен? Или еще что-то.

Ну и пару примерных рулей, если подкинете для пинка в нужном направлении, тоже спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ip route add default via eth1iptables -A POSTROUTRING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADEiptables -A POSTROUTRING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADEiptables -A POSTROUTRING -o eth3 -j MASQUERADE
```

PROFIT)